# Invalid column in select list with group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select
    fooditemid,
    sum(mealsize) as mealsize,
    mealdate
from Phase2FoodItems
where`
    userid = 190
    and mealdate between
        (select dietstartdate from Users where userid = 190)
        and GETDATE()
group by mealdate
```

I understand that this is basically asking SQL to give me data without providing enough information (it doesn't know what it should do with columns not specified in the group by, i.e. sum, average, etc).

Unfortunately, adding all the rest of the columns into the group by doesn't give me the sum'd values I'm looking for, for the `mealsize` column. In fact, the data I'm getting back is exactly the same as what I'd get without the sum and group by.

I think I'm missing a concept here, can anyone explain and/or suggest a new sql statement that will get me the sum of the mealsize column for each value in the mealdate column?

Comment: As it stands, this query won't execute - fooditemid is neither aggregated nor grouped.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using an `Aggregate` ([SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259238%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)) function, you will need to specify all other columns in your `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select
    fooditemid,
    sum(mealsize) as mealsize,
    mealdate
from Phase2FoodItems
where
    userid = 190
    and mealdate between
        (select dietstartdate from Users where userid = 190)
        and GETDATE()
group by mealdate, fooditemid
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I don't understand is why, after adding fooditemid into the group by, it's not doing either the SUM or grouping... The data I'm getting from this is exactly the same data I'd get if I didn't bother with either SUM or group by

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a column in the select clause, if that column does not appear in the group by clause (i.e. `fooditemid` in your case.) If you want to retain `fooditemid` column, while having a sum of `mealsize`, you can get this sum in a subquery. For example:

```
select
    outertable.fooditemid,
    outertable.mealdate,
    subquery.mealsize
from 
    Phase2FoodItems outertable
    inner join
    (
      select sum(inner.mealsize) mealsize
      from Phase2FoodItems inner
      where inner.userid = 190
        and inner.mealdate between
          (select dietstartdate from Users where userid = 190)
          and GETDATE() 
      group by inner.mealdate, inner.fooditemid
    ) subquery
    on subquery.fooditemid = outer.fooditemid
where
    outertable.userid = 190
    and outertable.mealdate between
        (select dietstartdate from Users where userid = 190)
        and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

All columns to be grouped by should be present in your GROUP BY clause for SQL Server to start with... other RDBMS are more forgiving and will return the first value for a non-agregated column instead of erroring.

Where you added other columns in you found that you got to the finest level of granularity your table holds - you need to work out exactly what level of granularity you need and add those columns into your GROUP BY and SELECT and not refer to the others columns in your SELECT.

Comment: In many respects I agree with you - I use both on a daily basis, but I've seen so many people get into trouble with this scenario that I think I prefer the more stringent requirements sql server make you adhere to :-)

Comment: Seems my solution was simpler than these answers suggest, but that's my fault. Having included `fooditemid` in the select, I gave the impression that I actually needed it. Having removed it from my select, the query works with only `group by mealdate`

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns...
So this Will remove Your Error...

```
select
    fooditemid,
    sum(mealsize) as mealsize,
    mealdate
from Phase2FoodItems
where`
    userid = 190
    and mealdate between
        (select dietstartdate from Users where userid = 190)
        and GETDATE()
group by mealdate, fooditemid
```

But this will group your data by both columns i.e. mealdate & fooditemid..So if you want data grouped by only by meal date than you can try below query...

```
Select fooditemid, mealsize,
 mealdate from (
Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By Meal Date Order By fooditemid) as Row,
     fooditemid,
     sum(mealsize) as mealsize,
     mealdate
    from Phase2FoodItems
     where`
     userid = 190
     and mealdate between
     (select dietstartdate from Users where userid = 190)
     and GETDATE()) t where Row=1
```